# NAudio - передача и воспроизведение mp3Frame через TCP

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, tcp, mp3, naudio

Я пишу TCP сервер-клиент приложение, часть которого которое реализует воспроизведение выбранного сервером .mp3 файла на всех подключённых клиентах.
Почитав, решил использовать библиотеку NAudio для обработки аудио. Вообще я новичок в работе со звуком.

Вот код передачи mp3:

```
    public void PlayFromFile(string fileName, UserList _clients)
    {
        Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(fileName);
        Mp3Frame frame;                                    
        // For each frame
        while ((frame = reader.ReadNextFrame()) != null)   
        {                                  
            foreach (var client in _clients)
            {
                NetworkStream outputStream = client.GetStream();
                outputStream.Write(frame.RawData, 0, frame.RawData.Length);
            }
        }
    }
```

> - UserList _clients - это CunncurrentDictionary, где в качестве значения выступают "AppUsers" - расширение стандартного класса TcpClient

Подскажите, правильный ли выбран подход для отправки пакетов приложениям-клиентам и если да - как лучше всего ловить и воспроизводить данные на стороне клиента?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подход неправильный по нескольким причинам.

1. Вы никак не отделяете разные фреймы друг от друга - в итоге получатель не сможет определить где заканчивается один и начинается другой. Напомню, что протокол TCP работает не с отдельными пакетами, а с потоком.
2. Вы используете TCP. TCP - это не лучший протокол для передачи в ситуации когда вам нужна стабильная задержка, но не нужна гарантия доставки. Для передачи реалтайм-аудио и видео лучше использовать UDP, а еще лучше - RTP.
3. Вы декодируете звук перед передачей по сети. Передача его в сжатом виде намного эффективнее...

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку.
Хотел ещё уточнить, как можно отделять фреймы между собой, дабы ничего не запороть и не испытывать сложностей на принемающей стороне?

Comment: @Sasha записывать длину фрейма перед содержимым. Но это нужно только при использовании TCP.